# Can you include multiple continuous variables in a meta-analysis?

Tags: statistics

I am looking to meta-analyze the differential effects of physical abuse and neglect on depression in a meta-analysis. If I come across a study the reports a correlation between a continuous measure of physical abuse and depression, and a separate continuous measure of neglect and depression, both using the total sample size, can I include both of these in the same meta-analysis?

Comment: I voted to migrate this to https://stats.stackexchange.com.